# How to set checked attribute to radio in litelement

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, lit-element, lit-html

I would like to know how to set checked to radio button using litelement.
I have a object and for each object options, radio button is created.

For example, for `id=SG` two radio buttons are created,
if no checked, set bank as default checked 
else set corresponding selected radio value as checked.

I got stuck in litelement.

```
const obj= [{
    id: "SG",
    options: ["bank", "credit"]
  },
  {
    id: "TH",
    options: ["bank"]
  }
];
render(){
  ${obj.map((e)=>{
return html`
         <form>
            ${obj.options.map((option_value)=>{
                   return html`
                       <input class="form-check-input"  name="sending-${option_value}" type="radio" id="provider-send-${option_value}" value=${option_value} ?checked=${option_value=="bank"} > // not working
                         <label class="form-check-label">
                                ${option_value}
                         </label><br>
             `})}
          </form>
   })`;

}
```

```
Expected Output:
Set checked to corresponding radio selected
If no checked, set bank as default checked
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? Because you seem to be missing a `$` in `?checked={option_value=="bank"}`.

Comment: @dork, thanks for reply, in actual code have `$` ,updated code, sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets the checked attribute to true if the option is `bank`:

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class TestElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      countries: {
        type: Array,
      },
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.countries = [
      {
        id: 'SG',
        options: ['bank', 'credit'],
      },
      {
        id: 'TH',
        options: ['bank'],
      },
      {
        id: 'MY',
        options: ['credit'],
      }
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      ${this.countries.map(country => html`
        <fieldset>
          <legend>${country.id}</legend>
          <form>
            ${country.options.map(option => html`
              <input
                id="provider-send-${option}"
                name="sending-${country.id}"
                type="radio"
                class="form-check-input"
                value="${option}"
                ?checked=${option === 'bank'}
              >
              <label class="form-check-label">${option}</label>
              <br>
            `)}
          </form>
        </fieldset>
      `)}
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('test-element', TestElement);
```

Looks like you just missed mapping the actual `obj` (`country` in my snippet).

Also, in order to change the selected radio, the `name` should be the same for all radios in a group. Your code is setting a different name to each radio.

Comment: thanks for reply, but what if radio option is `credit is checked` and will show `bank and credit checked` in radio

Comment: Sorry, what? Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: `?checked=${option === 'bank'}` this makes default bank option checked, what if user selects `credit` option and radio button will show both `bank and credit option checked` right

Comment: So basically acting like a normal radio group then? Then you should change the name of the radio group and not set the name to `sending-${option}`. `sending-${country.id}` would be better suited for this.

Comment: if i change also,  ` <input
                id="provider-send-${option}-${country.id}"
                name="sending-${option}-${country.id}"
                type="radio"
                class="form-check-input"
                value="${option}"
                ?checked=${option === 'bank'}
              >` not working

Comment: `sending-${country.id}` not `sending-${option}-${country.id}`